# Update Number Field on Custom Object based on Opportunity Stage

Tags: process-builder, custom-object, workflow, field-update

I would like to update a Number field on a custom object when an opportunity's stage changes to one of a set of options (picklist).

I have multiple opportunities related to each object, and need to keep a count of which ones are "booked" (paid). I also need to retroactively trigger this for already existing opportunities/objects, and make sure the count is not added to when other fields on the opportunity page are edited.

I've tried making a process (screenshots below), but it doesn't seem to be working, and I can't use a workflow because if I make it an opportunity workflow, object fields aren't available in the actions and vice versa.

I am basically new to all of this, so any help is appreciated.

[image: My number field]

[image: Criteria in my process]
[image: Trying to update the number field]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Is `Sailing` a parent or child of Opportunity? And I'm assuming you renamed Opportunity's label to `Booking`?  Note that Process Builder and Workflow are deprecated so if this is new work, I'd recommend Flow where you have much more control

Comment: Sailing is an object, and yes Booking is an opportunity. I'll check out Flow, thanks!